# Linking pages in Swift Playgrounds [Xcode]

Tags: swift, xcode, markdown, swift-playground, xcplayground

I am new to swift playgrounds and ran into some problems while making a swift playground in Xcode.

This is my main Playground page

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
let secondScene = Index()
let master = FirstScene()
let root = UINavigationController(rootViewController: master)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = root
```

But when I tried adding Next Topic in both the source class in Swift and the playground page itself the link does not appear.

NOTE: I am using Swift Playgrounds in Xcode not a Playgroundbook on an iPad.

Also, inside sources folder of my main page I declared all `class`es as public, is that the right way to use the helper swift files in source?

I tried creating a new playground and added pages which have default links but still no output.
[image: New playground but assistant editor shows no links]

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your screenshot, you've got the code right. The syntax to link to the next page *is* `[Next Page!](@next)`. All you need to do now is:
- In the Xcode menu bar, click Editor
- Click 'Show Rendered Markup'

[image: Editor -> 'Show Rendered Markup' Menu]

That's it. You can place markup wherever you like. Remember to replace spaces with `%20` when linking to a playground page, e.g. `[My Page #2](My%20Other%20Page)`

Answer (score 3):

You would benefit from reading Apple's [Markup Formatting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497).

To create a link to another page you will do the same thing that I did above to create a link to that reference in Markdown:

`[Next Topic](Pretend%20Topic%20Name)`

You can actually do something like this as well:

`[Next Topic](@next)`

Comment: I tried [link name](@next)
But when i run it in assistant editor I don't see the link. Also should I place that in viewDidLoad() method of the class? or in playground page where I instantiate the class.
Also when I add  [link name](@next) it cannot locate the @next file when i try to open by clicking + cmd button